# How can I use the method (helper) defined in a view in another view?

Tags: hanami

Let's say I have a form defined in View

```
module Admin
  module Views
    module Dashboard
      class New
        include Admin::View

        def form
          form_for :link, routes.links_path do
            text_field :url
            submit 'Create'
          end
        end
...
```

Am I missing something? since example below doesn't work:

```
module Admin
  module Views
    module Dashboard
      class Index
        include Admin::View
        include Dashboard::New
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't to share code from one view to another this way. 
Your snippet does not work because Ruby does not allow to include classes in to another classes. So, if you want to do this - you should to use helper module. For your case it should looks like this:

```
module Admin
  module Helpers
    module Dashboard
      def form
        form_for :link, routes.links_path do
          text_field :url
          submit 'Create'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and include it in your view

```
module Admin
  module Views
    module Dashboard
      class New
        include Admin::View
        include Admin::Helpers::Dashboard

        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

or include it globally in your app

```
# apps/admin/application.rb

view.prepare do
  include Hanami::Helpers
  include Admin::Helpers::Dashboard
end
```

documentation: https://guides.hanamirb.org/helpers/custom-helpers/